# NullpointerException on release build when I call one object in onResponse

Tags: android

When I am making release build it is giving null pointer somewhere. I have figured it out 
       when I add `getData.getDoctorNotes()` it crash but not on debug build. I am not able to understand what 
       is the actual issue but the same code is running perfect in another application.

```
   //json
   {
"status": true,
"errors": [],
"data": {
    "Labs": [],
    "Rads": [],
    "Pharmacy": [],
    "Doctor_Notes": {},
    "Referal_Admission": "N",
    "Referal_Procedure": "N"
   }
}

     call.enqueue(new Callback<OpdHistoryResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<OpdHistoryResponse> call, Response<OpdHistoryResponse> response) 
         {

            viewsEnable();
            if (response.body() != null) {
                OpdHistoryResponse jresponse = response.body();
                // when I call getData() it does not crash but when I call getData.getDoctorNotes
                   it does not crash, this happen only on release build debug build is running 
                   perfectly fine

                if (response.body() != null && response.body().isStatus()
                        && jresponse != null
                        && jresponse.getData().getDoctorNotes() != null && 
                      jresponse.getData().getDoctorNotes() != null) {
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(jresponse.getData().getDoctorNotes().getClinicalHistory()) 
                     &&
                            jresponse.getData().getDoctorNotes().getClinicalHistory() != null &&
                            !jresponse.getData().getDoctorNotes().getClinicalHistory().equals("")) {


           tvClinicalHistory.setText(jresponse.getData().getDoctorNotes().getClinicalHistory());
                    } else {
                        tvClinicalHistory.setText(R.string.no_data_found);
                    }

                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(jresponse.getData().getDoctorNotes().getDiagnosis()) &&
                            jresponse.getData().getDoctorNotes().getDiagnosis() != null &&
                            !jresponse.getData().getDoctorNotes().getDiagnosis().equals("")) {
                        tvDiagnosis.setText(jresponse.getData().getDoctorNotes().getDiagnosis());
                    } else {
                        tvDiagnosis.setText(R.string.no_data_found);
                    }

                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(jresponse.getData().getDoctorNotes().getTPlan()) &&
                            jresponse.getData().getDoctorNotes().getTPlan() != null &&
                            !jresponse.getData().getDoctorNotes().getTPlan().equals("")) {
                        tvPlan.setText(jresponse.getData().getDoctorNotes().getTPlan());
                    } else {
                        tvPlan.setText(R.string.no_data_found);
                    }

                } else {
                    dataNotFound();
                    tvNoDatFound.setText(R.string.no_data_found);
                }
            }else {
                dataNotFound();
                tvNoDatFound.setText(R.string.no_data_found);
            }
        }
```

This is response class where all models are available and using in the fragment classes

```
//model class
public class OpdHistoryResponse {

@SerializedName("data")
private OpdHistoryDataModel data;

@SerializedName("errors")
private List<Object> errors;

@SerializedName("status")
private boolean status;

public void setData(OpdHistoryDataModel data){
    this.data = data;
}

public OpdHistoryDataModel getData(){
    return data;
}

public void setErrors(List<Object> errors){
    this.errors = errors;
}

public List<Object> getErrors(){
    return errors;
}

public void setStatus(boolean status){
    this.status = status;
}

public boolean isStatus(){
    return status;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return 
        "OpdHistoryResponse{" +
        "data = '" + data + '\'' + 
        ",errors = '" + errors + '\'' + 
        ",status = '" + status + '\'' + 
        "}";
     }
}
```

inside above one model class this one getData

```
  public class OpdHistoryDataModel {

@SerializedName("Labs")
private List<String> labs;

@SerializedName("Pharmacy")
private List<Object> pharmacy;

@SerializedName("Doctor_Notes")
private OpdDoctorNotesModel doctorNotes;

@SerializedName("Rads")
private List<String> rads;

@SerializedName("Referal_Procedure")
private String referalProcedure;

@SerializedName("Referal_Admission")
private String referalAdmission;

public void setLabs(List<String> labs){
    this.labs = labs;
}

public List<String> getLabs(){
    return labs;
}

public void setPharmacy(List<Object> pharmacy){
    this.pharmacy = pharmacy;
}

public List<Object> getPharmacy(){
    return pharmacy;
}

public void setDoctorNotes(OpdDoctorNotesModel doctorNotes){
    this.doctorNotes = doctorNotes;
}

     //when this object call it gives null pointer in third tab fragment on release build
public OpdDoctorNotesModel getDoctorNotes(){
    return doctorNotes;
}

public void setRads(List<String> rads){
    this.rads = rads;
}

public List<String> getRads(){
    return rads;
}

public void setReferalProcedure(String referalProcedure){
    this.referalProcedure = referalProcedure;
}

public String getReferalProcedure(){
    return referalProcedure;
}

public void setReferalAdmission(String referalAdmission){
    this.referalAdmission = referalAdmission;
}

public String getReferalAdmission(){
    return referalAdmission;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return 
        "OpdHistoryDataModel{" +
        "labs = '" + labs + '\'' + 
        ",pharmacy = '" + pharmacy + '\'' + 
        ",doctor_Notes = '" + doctorNotes + '\'' + 
        ",rads = '" + rads + '\'' + 
        ",referal_Procedure = '" + referalProcedure + '\'' + 
        ",referal_Admission = '" + referalAdmission + '\'' + 
        "}";
    }
 }
```

inside above one this one getDoctorNotes()

```
     public class OpdDoctorNotesModel {

@SerializedName("t_plan")
private String tPlan;

@SerializedName("clinical_history")
private String clinicalHistory;

@SerializedName("diagnosis")
private String diagnosis;

public void setTPlan(String tPlan){
    this.tPlan = tPlan;
}

public String getTPlan(){
    return tPlan;
}

public void setClinicalHistory(String clinicalHistory){
    this.clinicalHistory = clinicalHistory;
}

public String getClinicalHistory(){
    return clinicalHistory;
}

public void setDiagnosis(String diagnosis){
    this.diagnosis = diagnosis;
}

public String getDiagnosis(){
    return diagnosis;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return 
        "OpdDoctorNotesModel{" +
        "t_plan = '" + tPlan + '\'' + 
        ",clinical_history = '" + clinicalHistory + '\'' + 
        ",diagnosis = '" + diagnosis + '\'' + 
        "}";
    }
 }
```

Comment: check your build.gradle, if minfyEnabled is true comment that then check, It can be a progaurd issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using GSON and you have the problem only in release, I assume you don't have proguard rules for GSON implemented:

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-dontwarn sun.misc.**
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { <fields>; }

# Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapter, TypeAdapterFactory,
# JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapter
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

# Prevent R8 from leaving Data object members always null
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
  @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
```

Original file here: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg

Comment: Thanks for the response but I am using retrofit (GSON) for the whole project why it is not crashing for other calls? I have issue with only one object

Comment: coroutineDispatcher  Thank you very very much I have done this it is working perfectly fine you have told me the exact problem :) I really appreciate God bless you.

Comment: Glad I helped. If your issue has been resolved please mark it as finished.